# JQuery div isn't hidden when 'close' is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have (what I'm sure is) a beginner question about JQuery.

I'm trying to make a div popup when an image is clicked. (There are multiple instances of this on one page, btw.)

However, the div doesn't close when 'close' is clicked.

Here's the JQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Set up bubble CSS when page is loaded so bubble info is hidden unless user acts.
// If JavaScript is turned off bubble info displays normally.
//
//

  $('.bubble_wrapper').css('position', 'relative');
  $('.bubble_info').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'none'
  });
  $('.bubble_close').css('display', 'block');
});

$(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $('.bubble_wrapper').each(function() {
    var trigger = $('#bubble_trigger'+counter, this);
    var popup = $('#bubble_info'+counter, this);

    $([trigger.get(0), popup.get(0)]).click(function() {
      $('.bubble_info').css('display', 'none');
      popup.css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.bubble_close').click(function() {
      $('.bubble_info').css('display', 'none');
    });

    counter += 1;
  });
});
```

And here's the html (I'm working in Rails, btw)...

```
<section id="latest_articles">
  <ul>
    <% id_counter = 1 %>
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <li class="bubble_wrapper">
        <%= image_tag(article.image_url(:thumb), :class => "bubble_trigger", :id => "bubble_trigger"+id_counter.to_s) if article.image? %>
        <div class="bubble_info" id=<%= "bubble_info"+id_counter.to_s %> >
          <h1><%= link_to article.title, article %></h1>
          <p><%= article.description %></p>
          <a class="bubble_close">Close</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <% id_counter += 1 %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try $('.bubble_info').hide() inside the click event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this, [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent the click click from bubbling up to its parent.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sxqNf/)

```
$('.bubble_close').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      $('.bubble_info').css('display', 'none');
    });
```

What happened here is the click event attached to the parent  `$([trigger.get(0), popup.get(0)])` opens up the div , but the `close` button is inside the div which has its own click event. So clicking on close div, its click event propagated to its parent. So it closes and opens again. `stopPropagation` prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

On a different note you can use [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead of making `display:block and hide` manually assigning css properties..

```
popup.css('display', 'block');
```

instead you can use

```
popup.show();
```

similarly

```
 $('.bubble_info').css('display', 'none');
```

you can use

```
  $('.bubble_info').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the super answer! I really appreciate the explanation and extra tip!